# Can't echo array properly

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, fetch

My table in the database contains 3 columns that all has qwe for a username and have the respective dates of January, February and March but when I try to echo them it only displays January. I'm trying to get them all into a drop down list but I can't get past this so I have to make sure I get all of these dates before I put them elsewhere.

```
{   
$con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysqli_error());
mysqli_select_db($con, 'useddates') or die("cannot select DB");

$request="SELECT date FROM mytable WHERE username='qwe'";
$result=mysqli_query($con, $request);
$fetch=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

echo $fetch['date']; echo "<br>";
print_r($fetch);
}
```

Comment: Just loop the the results. A basic PHP/MySQL tutorial always shows how to do this.

Comment: Oh okay thanks. My code doesn't have anything wrong right? It's just I'm missing a loop?

Comment: Yep. You're almost there. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing loop, data come up. You can see when you are printing data using **print_r($fetch)**, use loop to show one by one.
And also try to don't use user input directly in query before checking **mysql injection**. like you have putted **username='qwe'** if username is user input then use it like this directly in query **Suggestion for query**

```
$request = "SELECT date FROM mytable WHERE username=".mysql_real_escape_string('qwe');
```

and your with loop try this,

```
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die(mysqli_error());
mysqli_select_db($con, 'useddates') or die("cannot select DB");

$request = "SELECT date FROM mytable WHERE username='qwe'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $request);
print_r($fetch);
while ($fetch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $fetch['date'];
    echo "<br>";
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This definitely did the trick! I was playing around with foreach and my result was an infinite amount of January (I could hear my system unit's processing xD). If you don't mind me asking, what are the drawbacks if I use username='qwe' rather than the one you suggested?

Comment: You are welcome @CarlDun. No dear i will never mind you can see Doc here related to what i suggestin sql injection above. http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysql-php-sql-injection.php

Comment: Thanks again. You've not only help me on my problem but also helped me on the security of my program! This is a huge information as I wasn't even aware on the types of attack in php.